# I want to add data in mongo collection while updating, but instead its getting updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add data while I am updating, So the use cases is to add the data in same object when I am making a for loop to store the data into the database. But When I am trying to do this then its getting updated instead of adding in into current present object.

```
const update_records = async (_id, fileName, filter) => {
  
    try {

        await connect_to_mongo();

        const result = await execute_reports_model.findOneAndUpdate(_id, {upsert: true}, function (err, doc){
            if(err || doc === null){
                console.error(err);
                const e = new Error('ID not found.');
                e.status = 404;
                throw e;
            }

            doc.file_name = fileName;
            doc.filters.id = filter._id
            doc.filters.name = filter.name
            doc.filters.origin = filter.origin
            doc.save();
        })
        
   

        return result;

    } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);
        throw error;

    }
}
```

In above function i am trying to add data into existing data which is present in the mongo collection.(using mongoose)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f16f4e1291796bb531a06df"),
    "student)_count" : 5,
    "batch_key" : "ddddwe3-6e4a-4654-8f18-c44b152c52c3",
    "report_id" : "5f0ffbcdd264d70c1a3b143aa",
    "__v" : 0,
    "file_name" : "Student Copy Demand file",
    "filters" : {
        "id" : "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
        "name" : "USER 2 cards filter",
        "origin" : "USER"
    }
}
```

Lets say this above is the data available in the collection.

Now i one for loop I am updating the data with id of the same data.

```
await update_records(_id, fileName, row);
```

here in above code, `row` is for loop `row` which contains filters, and filters needs to be added with filename in the existing record for which that I will find by that `_id`

example if row contains below data

```
 {
        "id" : "2f0f3fb496d670c513iuroinm",
        "name" : "Student Daily attendence",
        "origin" : "Student"
    }
```

Then that updated record would look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f16f4e1291796bb531a06df"),
    "student)_count" : 5,
    "batch_key" : "ddddwe3-6e4a-4654-8f18-c44b152c52c3",
    "report_id" : "5f0ffbcdd264d70c1a3b143aa",
    "__v" : 0,
    "file_name" : "Student Copy Demand file",
    "filters" : {
        "id" : "5f0ffb96d67d70c1a3b143e7",
        "name" : "USER 2 cards filter",
        "origin" : "USER"
    },
    {
            "id" : "2f0f3fb496d670c513iuroinm",
            "name" : "Student Daily attendence",
            "origin" : "Student"
        }
}
```

Also this is how my model looks like

```
report_id:{type:String,trim:true},
file_name:{type:String},
filters:[{
    status:{type:String}, // this would updated in another function
        id:{type:String},
      name:{type:String},
    origin:{type:String}
 }],
batch_key:{type:String,trim:true},
```

How can I achieve this?

Edited: Made Model filters Array

```
const result = await execute_reports_model.findByIdAndUpdate(
            _id, 
            {
                $set:
                {
                    filters: [filters_data],
                }
            });
```

This above code is updating the filed not inserting another one.
All I want to add new, not update the existing.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to add new filter object to the `filters` field, but `filters` field is the object so it's always replaced.
To add new filter in the `filters`, you must make `filters` array and then just append it.

Comment: Updated the question, if you could help

Answer (score 0):

Here first of all your model is depicting the wrong meaning. Your filters should be an array.

If you want more than one object to be stored with commas you should have the array data type for the filters.

Make other model for the object that you need to store in the array of filters.

Lets call it **filterModel**.

Then your main model should look like:

```
 report_id:{type:String,trim:true},
    file_name:{type:String},
    filters: filterModel[]=[]
    batch_key:{type:String,trim:true},
```

And your filterModel should have the following:

```
 status:{type:String}, // this would updated in another function
        id:{type:String},
      name:{type:String},
    origin:{type:String}
```

Edited:

Hello, instead of using set operation you should use push operation to add the entry in the array and not replace the existing values.
So please try the below line of codes.

```
const result = await execute_reports_model.findByIdAndUpdate(
        _id, 
        {
            $push:
            {
                filters: filters_data,
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you help here?

Comment: Then how could I call `findOneAndUpdate` and save/insert new datas/records?

Comment: Updated the question